# Explode array of structs to columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, explode

I'd like to explode an array of structs to columns (as defined by the struct fields). E.g.

```
    root
 |-- news_style_super: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sbox_ctr: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- wise_ctr: double (nullable = true)
```

Should be transformed to

```
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- sbox_ctr: double (nullable = true)
|-- wise_ctr: double (nullable = true)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are a new contributor and welcome, but this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_final_dataframe(pathname, df):
cur_names = pathname.split(".")
if len(cur_names) > 1:
    root_name = cur_names[0]
    delimiter = "."
    new_path_name = delimiter.join(cur_names[1:len(cur_names)])

    for field in df.schema.fields:
        if field.name == root_name:
            if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType:
                return get_final_dataframe(pathname, df.select(explode(root_name).alias(root_name)))
            elif type(field.dataType) == StructType:
                if hasColumn(df, delimiter.join(cur_names[0:2])):
                    return get_final_dataframe(new_path_name, df.select(delimiter.join(cur_names[0:2])))
                else:
                    return -1, -1
            else:
                return -1, -1

else:
    root_name = cur_names[0]
    for field in df.schema.fields:
        if field.name == root_name:
            if type(field.dataType) == StringType:
                return df, "string"
            elif type(field.dataType) == LongType:
                return df, "numeric"
            elif type(field.dataType) == DoubleType:
                return df, "numeric"
            else:
                return df, -1

return -1, -1
```

then,you can

```
key = "a.b.c.name"
# key = "context.content_feature.tag.name"
df2, field_type = get_final_dataframe(key, df1)
```